# C# Validating xml file against xsd: "The 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace:lang' attribute is not declared"

Tags: xml

I am trying to validate an xml file against an xsd file and continue to run into this error:
"The 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace:lang' attribute is not declared."

My program works without issues when I use example xml and xsd files from this Microsoft tutorial (contosoBooks.xml and contosoBooks.xsd):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.validate?view=net-7.0

But when I use my own xml and xsd files, I get the attribute not declared error.

This is the top of my xsd file with some text replaced with dummy text:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="dummytargetNamespace"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:tns="dummytns"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">

  <!-- Import definition for xml:lang -->
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd" />
```

I have tried a bunch of different things, particularly following the advice from this question:
["The 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace:lang' attribute is not declared."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117627/the-http-www-w3-org-xml-1998-namespacelang-attribute-is-not-declared)

But have not had any luck.

The xml and xsd files in question validate without issue when using an online validator tool.

Thanks in advance.

Tried to validate xml file against xsd file. Expected a comparison result.

Comment: You have a namespace "lang" in your xml with no URL associated with the namespace.  What did you change from the xml in the link?  You are probably missing the default namespace `xmlns="http://www.contoso.com/books"`

Comment: Please supply a minimal but complete schema and source document that demonstrate the problem, and tell us which schema processor you used.

Comment: While asking an XSD question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSD that tried to implement it.
(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.